# How to add MongoLab addon without creating default database?

Tags: node.js, heroku, mlab

It's a simple question:

I have an database in MongoLab. And I have an app on Heroku. I added the MongoLab addon. Then I just change the MONGOLAB_URI environment variable to my database and it's working. But the default database, created when I added the addon, still lives.

Is there any way for adding the MongoLab addon on Heroku without creating the default database?

Thank's. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an account directly with mongolab.com, you don't need to use the Heroku add-on at all.  They're completely independent.  Just delete the add-on and make up your own environment variable to store the URI pointing to your database (e.g. MONGODB_URI).

Comment: Perfect! Very easy solution. Why didn't I think of that? Thank you very much bro. :)